# How to create useful tests for fixed byte values

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I am working on an android application with Bluetooth iot devices. Theses devices sends broadcasts periodically in the form of 30ish bytes containing various information.

Some of the bytes have specific values akin to enums or flags and some have fixed values like the product type which is always the same.

For now I have functions that decode parts of the bytes and transforms them as needed. In pseudo code it looks like that :

```
boolean isHeaderValid(bytes[] payload) { 
    return (payload[0] == 0x1 && payload[1] == 0x81);
}

ProductColor productColor(bytes[] payload) { 
    switch (byte[22]) {
        case 0x00: return ProductColor.RED;
        case 0x01: return ProductColor.GREEN;
        case 0x02: return ProductColor.BLUE;
    }
    return ProductColor.UNKNOWN;
}
```

With this kinds of predicaments how should I create meaningful unit tests to validate my functions ?

Here are my thoughts so far :

- I could test valid cases only: `assert(isHeaderValid(0x0181))`
- I could use range validation but I still have to loop on all values to validate all the possibilities :

```
for (i in 0 .. Short.MAX) {
    if (i < 0x0181 && 0x0181 < i) 
        assert(not(isHeaderOk(bytes(i))))
    else 
        assert(isHeaderOk(bytes(i)))
}
```

I can limit on the loop by checking byte by byte.

- I could use neighbors of the range bounds to check for all values that are out of range.

Maybe I overthinks it and it is useless to do theses kinds of tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not think it is necessary to do an exhaustive testing.

A typical approach would be to:

- Test a few valid values
- Test a few invalid values
- Test values that are specifically near "borders", like the smallest/largest valid and invalid values.

But you might want consider why you want to unit test your code. Just testing if two bytes have some predetermined values would not be very valuable in my opinion. Since the complexity is so low. Tests should be written because they help you in some way, not because people on the internet tell you that you should write unit tests.

You could also test larger 'modules', i.e. do not test the code that checks the header, check the code that receives a full package and does something with this package. Record some packages from devices and check that these are handled like they should. You might also generate some random data and check that this is also handled like expected.

You might also want to consider what could go wrong, and how such failures are handled. For example, if it is possible to receive bytes with the wrong endianess it could be useful to check for such a case and give an error that alert the operator about such an error.